# Is it possible to specify an array inline with LINQ?

Tags: c#

I am using this code:

```
var values = new[] { 15, 30, 50 };
if (Settings.Rev == REV.No && values.Any(v => v == Settings.Trk2))
```

is there a way I could eliminate the need to assign to values and just do an Any direct in this instance? Can anyone see any possible issues that might come up if I do this?

Also is there a way I could reverse it around with something like Settings.Trk2 on the left hand side to make it a bit clearer that I want to check if it has a value of 15, 30 or 50?

Comment: You mean like this? `(new[] { 15, 30, 50 }).Any(v => v == Settings.Trk2)`
It has no problems that I can think of.

Comment: I was just a bit concerned about putting a new inside of an if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it this way:

```
if (Settings.Rev == REV.No && (new[] { 15, 30, 50 }).Contains(Settings.Trk2))
```

This approach is slightly better when `Settings.Rev != REV.No` because in this case the array won't even be created.

### Update

I suggest that you put all values inside a `HashSet<int>` to quickly check if it contains the specified value.

```
var set = new HashSet<int> { 15, 30, 50 };
if (Settings.Rev == REV.No && set.Contains(Settings.Trk2))
    ...
```

It is preferred to keep the `HashSet` constructed once and then updated overtime. This means that you need to define the `HashSet` as field of a class and use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this:

```
if (Settings?.Rev == REV.No && Array.IndexOf(new[] { 15, 30, 50 }, Settings?.Trk2) != -1)
```

For arrays, I'll probably stick with array methods instead of LINQ.
Personally, I favour readability than reducing number of lines.

**Update:**

```
if (Array.IndexOf(new[] { 15, 30, 50 }, Settings?.Trk2) != -1)
    if (Settings?.Rev == REV.No)
{
 // rest of the code.
}
```